# Android : Sharing facebook session object among various activities

Tags: android, facebook, session, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I need to implement facebook's share feature into my android app. My scenario is that I have to be able to use the facebook object created in the launch screen among all the other activities. I have already checked into the related questions in SO & found below mentioned links. Now I am guessing, which one of them is the ideal way to implement. Please let me know your views on these methods or If you have your own approach please let me know.

[Sharing a global facebook object across Android activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276354/sharing-a-global-facebook-object-across-android-activities)

[Facebook android: passing facebook object between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419499/facebook-android-passing-facebook-object-between-activities)

[Android: Passing a Facebook session across activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558973/android-passing-a-facebook-session-across-activities?rq=1)

[Facebook wall post from multiple Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361288/not-able-to-call-facebook-feature-on-other-activitys)
In the answers mentioned above

**First Solution** deals with creating the facebook object within application context and sharing across the application:

```
public class GlobalVars extends Application {

public static final String APP_ID = "123456789";    
public Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
```

}

**Second Solution** states the use of sharedprefernces. after creating a valid facebook session, it is stored in sharedpreferences and restored back in each activity when required.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("facebook",MODE_PRIVATE);
String access_token = prefs.getString("access_token", null);
long expires = prefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
if(access_token != null) {
facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
}
if(expires != 0) {
facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
}
```

**Third Solution** states the use of parcelable implementation.

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
out.writeInt(mData);
```

}

**Fourth solution** is trying to create a class containing static Facebook object and trying to use the same from all activities.

```
Class Utiltiy {
public static Facebook mFacebook;

public static void initialize() {
   mFacebook = new Facebook(app_id);
}
}

Utility.mFacebook.request(....).
```

Thanks for going through whole post. Please suggest a suitable approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one more approach with storing facebook credentials in [Android Account Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html). 
If user installed facebook app and already logged in you can get his credentials from Account Manager. And this method gives users a central point (Settings -> Accounts) to define its credentials. From there you can customize them or even delete them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I appreciate your time in suggesting a new method for fetching the credentials. But I guess its complicated. I am using facebook sdk in my application, so that it can handle fetching the token for us.